# Snowflake insert date error, are lowercase field names and field names with only initial capital letters considered to be the same field name?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a new table.

```
create table test(
    "device" varchar default null,
    "Device" varchar default null
);
```

Try to insert data.

```
insert into test ("device")
values ('iphone');
```

insert succeeded.

```
insert into test ("Device")
values ('mini');
```

insert succeeded.

```
insert into test ("device", "Device")
values ('iphone', 'mini');
```

insert error.
error message`[42S21][2025] SQL compilation error: duplicate column name '"Device"'`

Comment: Why would you want to identically named columns in different case? Whether or not this is a bug, you're inviting trouble

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the initial capital letters. It's about INSERT command and double quoted columns. This is a known issue which the development team is already working on it. If you submit a case to Snowflake Support, they can apply a fix for this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are some facts how Snowflake deals the Identifier, I have tried to put only two  relevant facts to the context.

Before that what an identifier is? these are first class snowflake object names, including ***"COLUMN NAME"*** for a 'table' parent object

**Rule 1**

If you put double quotes around an identifier the following rules apply:

```
The identifier is case-sensitive.   
The identifier can contain and even start with any ASCII character from the blank character (32) to the tilde (126), excluding the double quote.
```

Check : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html

***Rule-2***

```
  Snowflake suggests "Identifiers for columns must be unique within the table"
```

check : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers.html

As per your question, you are not following the rule-2 so you are getting that error.